# About absolute continuity of borel measures

Tags: measure-theory

Assume that $\mu, \nu$ are two borel measures on $\mathbb{R}$, so that $\mu<<\nu$.
Is it true that:

1. $\nu$ is finite $\Rightarrow$ $\mu$ is finite?
2. $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite $\Rightarrow$ $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite?
3. $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite $\Rightarrow$ $\mu$ is finite on bounded borel sets?

I know these questions are very basic and I really thought they would be easy to answer, but unfortunately I can't find proofs nor counter-examples (though I tend to believe that the statements aren't true).

Any ideas?

EDIT: As I thought, all of there are incorrect. There are two useful statements that help here:

- If $\mu$ is a non-zero $\sigma$-finite measure then there is a probability measure $P$ such that $\mu<<P, P<<\mu$.
- If $\mu$ is a measure then the function $\lambda(E)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
  0 & \mu(E)=0\\ \infty & else 
  \end{matrix}\right.
  $ is also a measure.

Comment: Consider the particular case $d\mu = f \cdot d\nu$ and you will gets your answers / counter examples.

Comment: Thank you! I'll edit with the simple answers I found